# How to use Vuex in Vue3 Component with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I created a new VueJS 3 project with Typescript. Further I added Vuex 4 as my store. But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong to import the store into my Vue Component.

Currently I get an error in my browser's console:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null**

How must I import my store to use it in my component?

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { store, key } from "./store/store";

createApp(App)
    .use(store, key)
    .mount('#app')

// store.ts
import {InjectionKey} from "vue"
import {createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store} from "vuex"

export interface State {
    ...
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol()

export const store = createStore<State>({
    state: {
        someArray: [{...}]
    },
    mutations: {},
    getters: {
        getObjects: (state) => state.someArray
    }
})

export function useStore() {
    return baseUseStore(key)
}

// Component
<template>...</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue";
import {useStore} from "../store/store";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Comp',
  data() {
    return {
      store: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    something() {
      return this.store.getters.getObjects
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    return store
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're mixing the Composition API with the Options API. You've declared your own `store` data property, and then in `setup()`, you're re-declaring `store` by returning it.

To resolve the issue, just remove the `data` and `computed` options, and stick with the Composition API (just use `setup`):

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ something }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from '../store/store'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    return {
      something: computed(() => store.getters.getObjects)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```